# include many unnumbered section in the TOC with correct page reference

Tags: table-of-contents

I am trying to include more than one unnumbered section in the TOC of my thesis. I used `\chapter*{Summary}` and `\chapter*{Samenvatting}` to define the unnumbered sections and `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Summary}` and `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Samenvatting}` to add them to the TOC. Summary starts at page 1...and it comes correct in the TOC, but Samenvatting starts at page 3 and in the TOC it appears again page 1. Here is my document:

```
\documentclass[10pt,b5paper,openright,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[width=170.00mm, height=240.00mm, left=2.0cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.2 cm, bottom=1.80cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage[font={small},labelfont={bf}]{caption} %to set caption font small and with bold label
\captionsetup[table]{skip=5pt} %to add space below table caption
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2} % to increase row heigth in tables


\makeatletter % to set the layout of the chapters header
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{60\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        %\huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \huge\bfseries \thechapter.\space%
        %\par\nobreak
        %\vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother



\usepackage{fancyhdr} %necessary to set your own header and footer style
\pagestyle{fancy} %necessary to set your own header and footer style
\fancyhf{} %clear the header and the footer before you define your own
\fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage} %footer in odd pages on the right
\fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage} %footer in even pages on the left

\renewcommand\bibname{{{\tiny } }References} %change bibliography to References

\author{Elisa Calignano}
\title{Elisa tesi}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter %the text between \frontmatter and \mainmatter will be numbered with roman numbers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %set the thickness of the header line in the frontmatter at 0

\clearpage %in order to remove page numbers from the title page
\thispagestyle{empty}

\include{titlepage}

\clearpage %in order to remove page numbers from the empy page before the tabel of contents
\thispagestyle{empty}


\tableofcontents
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} %to number subsections
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} %to include subsections number in the table of contents



\mainmatter

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5 pt}%set the thickness of the header line in the mainmatter at 0.5
\fancyhead[LE]{\slshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}%set header in even pages to the left=current chapter
\fancyhead[RO]{\slshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}%set header in odd pages to the right=current section

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Summary}% to add the summary to the table of contents witouth number
\include{summary}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Samenvatting}% to add the summary to the table of contents witouth number
\include{samenvatting}
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\include{chapter3}
\include{chapter4C}
\include{chapter5}
\include{chapter6}








\listoffigures

\listoftables

\bibliographystyle{apalike2}

\bibliography{Myref}

\backmatter
\include{author}
\include{acknowledgments}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) Welcome. (2) You might want to edit this MWE, as we of course do not have those chapters that are suppose to be included. Also the `\addcontentsline` stuff belongs at the text it refers to, not right before the TOC.

Comment: did you try to interchange the contentsline and chapter commands?

Comment: I tried to interchange the \addcontentsline and chapter as suggested by Bort...it worked once...but not the second time

Comment: Without all the missing files, we cannot test your not-so-minimal also-not-working example.  One point: it you want to get the page right you should put the \addtocontentsline AFTER the \section command, just in case the page breaks between the two.

Answer (score 2):

`\chapter*` effectively issues `\cleardoublepage` to ensure that the new chapter starts on its own page and that that is an odd (right-hand) page. So, when you say,

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Summary}% to add the summary to the table of contents witouth number
\include{summary}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Samenvatting}% to add the summary to the table of contents witouth number
\include{samenvatting}
```

what happens?

First, an addition is made to the `.toc` file including a reference to the current page. This is for the `Summary` entry.

Next, LaTeX checks whether there is anything on the current page and whether the current page is a right-hand page. Since there is nothing here and it is a right-hand page, LaTeX goes ahead and starts the chapter which you begin with `\chapter*{Summary}` on the current page. Since this matches the entry in the `.toc` file, all is well.

When it has finished typesetting the summary, the next instruction tells it to add an entry to the `.toc` file for `Samenvatting`. Again, it adds the reference to the current page.

Now, it finds the `\chapter*{Samenvatting}` so it checks whether there is anything on the current page. There is. There is all this `Summary` stuff. So, it clears the page and starts a new one. Now it checks if this is a right-hand page. It is not. We are on a left-hand page now. So, it clears another page and starts a new one. Now we are on a page which is empty and right-hand, so it starts the `Samenvatting` chapter. So now we are on page 3, but the entry in the `.toc` file was issued when we were still on page 1.

To avoid this, add the contents line immediately after issuing `\chapter*`. In this case, that's presumably in the included files we don't have. In `summary.tex`:

```
\chapter*{Summary}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Summary}
```

In `samenvatting.tex`:

```
\chapter*{Samenvatting}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Samenvatting}
```